# Timer on each row of dynamic table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one column as time and another column as timer. In time column I have a request creation Time and in timer column I want to set timer from a request creation time to the current IST time.

like if I have creation time as **1562307956195** then I want my timer as **15h20m** and getting increased on each sec.

table is kinda like this

```
<Table>
    <thead>
        <tr>   
            <th>Creation Time</th>   
            <th>Time Spent</th>   
            <th></th>   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1562307956195 </td>
            <td> 15H30M</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1562307956195 </td>
            <td> 15H30M</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</Table>
```

I want to timer count for each and every row. I am not figuring out how to do that dynamically.

I have tried:

```
state = {
    timer: 0,
    hours: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 0 
}; 

timer = (unix_timestamp) => {
    console.log('ts', unix_timestamp)
    var difference = unix_timestamp - Date.now();

    var hoursDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60);
    difference -= hoursDifference*1000*60*60

    var minutesDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60);
    difference -= minutesDifference*1000*60

    var secondssDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000);
    difference -= secondssDifference*1000*60
    this.setState({ hours: hoursDifference })
    this.setState({ minutes: minutesDifference })
    this.setState({ seconds: secondssDifference })
    console.log(d)
    return this.state.minutes + ':' + this.state.seconds 
}

<Table>
    <thead>
        <tr>  
            <th>Creation Time</th>   
            <th>Time Spent</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {this.state.serviceRequests.map((request,index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td> {this.getDate(request.createdAt)} </td>
            <td> {this.timer(request.createdAt)} </td>
        </tr>
    ))}
    </tbody>
</Table>
```

Comment: `moment` is a good time library with a lot of formatting options, are you allowed to use that?

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes, but how to set different timer for each row?

Comment: well assuming your rows are `serviceRequests` in your code, then you would already be doing that.

Comment: it's going to be same timer for all the requests as per this code. but I want different timer for ass rows based on creation time

Comment: ah, thats because you are using state here. You dont need state

Comment: How can I do that without state?

Comment: just dont set state. Just return the calculated difference with local variables in that function.

Comment: okay, but I want to update that on every second afterwards.

Comment: well then this sounds like a good use case for a second component. call it `Timer`. on `componentDidMount` you start your 1 second interval to set state. Dont try to return a value, just let the render method render the state value

Comment: Don't understand clearly, can you please give me example?

Answer (score 2):

You just want a timer component. Set up the `startTime` and state. Then update state in something like an `updateTime` function

```
class Timer extends Component {
  constructor(p) {
    super(p)
    this.interval = p.interval || 1000
    this.startTime = p.ts
    this.state = {
      ts: new Date().valueOf()
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval( () => {
      this.updateTime()
    }, this.interval)
  }
  updateTime = () => {
    this.setState({ts: new Date().valueOf()})
  }
  getFormattedTime = () => {
    return moment(this.startTime).fromNow()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td> {moment(this.startTime).format('MMM Do YY')} </td>
        <td> {this.getFormattedTime()} </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

Then your usage would be something like this

```
{this.state.serviceRequests.map(
  (request,index) => <Timer ts={request.createdAt} key={request.id} />
}
```

I'm not a huge fan of rendering specific elements like `<tr>` for a general use-case timer. So maybe pass a render function as a prop, that way you can specify how the time should be rendered. But thats a refactor for you :)

Edit

[**Here's a live example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5rotmj8a/)

Comment: Sorry it should be start time that we do the from now on. Try that

Comment: I think in `componentDidMount` ,`setTimeout` will not work I need to add `setInterval`

Comment: @Dweep yep, sorry I was writing blind code without testing so there's prolly a few errors in there. I'll add a working fiddle an update accordingly

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly you want to calculate time from request creation until current time.
You can use moment toNow() method.
Read more in this page of official docs. [toNow()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/tonow/)